# Pandas - Find a column with a specific value in the entire dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which has a few columns. There is a column with a value that only appears once in the entire dataframe. I want to write a function that returns the column name of the column with that specific value. I can manually find which column it is with the usual data exploration, but since I have multiple dataframes with the same properties, I need to be able to find that column for multiple dataframes. So a somewhat generalized function would be of better use.

The problem is that I don't know beforehand which column is the one I am looking for since in every dataframe the position of that particular column with that particular value is different. Also  the desired columns in different dataframes have different names, so I cannot use something like df['my_column'] to extract the column.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a workable example with input and your desired output.

Comment: do you know if the datatype is the in all scenarios?

Comment: @Manakin -- Yes the datatype is the same in all the scenarios.

Comment: `df.select_dtypes('your_dtype').eq('target_value').any()` should work. I echo @Stefan you should add some dummy data to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to iterate columns and look for the value:

```
def find_col_with_value(df, value):

    for col in df:
        if (df[col] == value).any():
             return col
```

This will return the name of the first column that contains `value`. If value does not exist, it will return `None`.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, your answer totally worked for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the entire DataFrame for the specific value, checking `any` to see if it ever appears in a column, then slice the columns (or the DataFrame if you want the Series)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 5, (100, 200)),
                  columns=[chr(i+40) for i in range(200)])
df.loc[5, 'Y'] = 'secret_value'  # Secret value in column 'Y'

df.eq('secret_value').any().loc[lambda x: x].index
# or
df.columns[df.eq('secret_value').any()]
```

---

```
Index(['Y'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score -1):

I have another solution:

```
names = ds.columns
for i in names:
    for j in ds[i]:
        if j == 'your_value':
            print(i)
            break
```

Here you are collecting all the names of columns and then iterating all dataset while it will be found. Then print the name of column.